# Convert Lync meeting to regular meeting

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, microsoft-office-2013, lync-2013

How can I convert a Lync meeting to a regular meeting in Outlook 2013?

If I remove the "join lync meeting" link the meetings remains as a lync meeting. The button in the ribbon för joining lync meeting remains.

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft, the only "true" way to convert it to a regular/in-person meeting is to cancel the meeting and create a new meeting.  As an alternative to that, Microsoft suggests exactly what you did -- removing the "Join Lync Meeting" link so that it appears to not be a Lync meeting (even though it still is).

More details here:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Cancel-a-Lync-or-Skype-meeting-d1d3741f-7f9b-4f48-a16f-7ba5e5d838c4?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1#_change

Answer (score 0):

This workaround did the job at least on Outlook 2016:

- In the body of the email, remove the full text of the “Join
  Lync/Skype Meeting” table.
- In the location of the email (below
  the subject), overwrite the text “Lync/Skype meeting” with else.

Then, choose whether:

- (complex option) Disabling the Skype plugin, in File - Options -
  Add-ins - select COM type and button GO… then disable Skype.

Or alternatively:

- (easy option) Change the email format to unformatted plain text: in the ribbon “Format Text” - select
  “plain text”.

If the latter worked for you, click on +1 on this answer!